# Is SList class an ADT?

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, linked-list

As per the definition given in [lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c4I3gFYe3w&list=PL79EB159504A5F429&index=8), ADT is,

[image]

With reference to this definition, I would like to call `SList` class an ADT following 6 invariants:

1. Multiple users of `SList` class should be consistent in usage with same `SList` instance. For example multiple users may insert items in same shopping list.
2. No runtime exceptions while using `SList` class when list is empty.
3. `SList` size member variable is always correct.
4. `SList` is never circularly linked list.
5. `SList` never returns `SListNode`, instead it return only an item.
6. Methods of the `SlistNode` class can be modified in future without any affect to `SList` class users. I guess this is nothing but encapsulation.

The below two classes will be part of a package and be used by classes from other packages:

```
class SListNode{
    Object item;
    SListNode next;
    public SListNode(){
        this.item = null;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public SListNode(Object item, SListNode next){
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
    public SListNode(Object item){
        this(item,null);
    }
    public void insertAfter(Object item){
        this.next = new SListNode(item,this.next);
    }
    public SListNode nth(int position){
        if(position ==1){
            return this;
        }else if((position < 1) || (this.next == null)){ /* error checking */
            return null;
        }else{
            SListNode tempNode = this.next.nth(position-1);
            return tempNode;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SList {
    private SListNode head; // First node in list.
    private int size; // Number of items in list.
    public SList() { // Here’s how to represent an empty list.
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    public void insertFront(Object item) {
        head = new SListNode(item, head);
        size++;
    }
    public void insertEnd(Object item){
        SListNode lastNode = this.head;
        while(lastNode.next != null){
            lastNode = lastNode.next;
        }
        lastNode.next = new SListNode(item,lastNode.next);
        size++;
    }
    public void insertAt(Object item, int position){
        if (position == 1){
            insertFront(item);
            size++;
        }else if(position < 1){
            System.exit(1);
        }else{
            SListNode currentNode = this.head.nth(position);
            if(currentNode != null){
                currentNode.insertAfter(item);
                size++;
            }else{
                System.exit(1); //position value exceeds 
            }
        }
    }
    public Object nth(int position){
        if(position < 1){
            return null;
        }else{
            SListNode tempNode = this.head.nth(position);
            if(tempNode != null){
                return tempNode.item;
            }
            else{
                return null; 
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (size==0);
    }
}
```

My question:
With reference to `SList` class as shown above, Can you please confirm if my interpretation of definition of ADT is correct? 
If the interpretation is wrong, What code changes would you like to see, to call `SList` as an ADT?

*Note:* I am yet to learn exception-handling, interfaces, inheritance, polymorphism and composition in class.

Comment: -1: Various bugs were found, leading me to believe that you failed to adequately try to confirm that your code works as intended.

Comment: Reading your last note, it seems I'm a bit overly harsh (removed downvote). I recommend getting a full understanding of the language and its features first though, because any comments we make will go over your head (such as throwing exceptions and providing proper API methods)

Comment: @Pimgd I like how you support your downvotes by leaving comments, but maybe sometimes before downvoting someone's question or answer it's better to point out a mistake? It just could be that it's not done on purpose. And when you make sure the mistake is intentional you can go ahead and downvote...

Comment: @zafarkhaja I believe that a simple for loop would have found the bug. `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ slist.insertAt(i, i); }` fails, because slist is 1-indexed. Start `i` at `1`, it still fails. I believe there has been 0 testing, which for me would invalidate the premise "To the best of my knowledge, does this code work?". Only later did I realize that the asker in question (haha) is still learning. I then lowered my expectations and standards a bit and took on a different tone.

Comment: @Pimgd Apologise for lowering your expectations and standards a bit.

Comment: @overexchange I'm not sure what you mean by that, but it's okay, really.

Comment: @Pimgd So, Do you think the class SListNode that wrote is easy to modify in future(Encapsulation)? Do you think the SList is a good Abstraction?

Comment: @overexchange I think you should use `java.util.List` and `java.util.LinkedList` before making your own. They're easy to modify, but that's because they're pretty small. I don't like what they do however... if they were meant to replace lists I'd argue that you have a rather large amount of changes to make.

Comment: @Pimgd My intention is not to replace java.util.List class, Instead, I would like to understand that, Whenever i think of building an Abstraction(like SList), Am i taking a right approach in terms of six points(invariants) that i mentioned in the query before building an Abstraction? For example, i made `SListNode` non-public so that i can modify any member method independently.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back your code from Rev 12 to Rev 4.

Answer (score 8):

Bug:

```
public void insertEnd(Object item){
    SListNode lastNode = this.head;
    while(lastNode.next != null){
        lastNode = lastNode.next;
    }
    lastNode.next = new SListNode(item,lastNode.next);
    size++;
}
```

Make a new list, add to end. `this.head` is null, so `lastNode.next` is a NullPointerException.

Bug:

```
public void insertAt(Object item, int position){
    if (position == 1){
        insertFront(item);
        size++;
    }else if(position < 1){
        System.exit(1);
    }else{
        SListNode currentNode = this.head.nth(position);
        if(currentNode != null){
            currentNode.insertAfter(item);
            size++;
        }else{
            System.exit(1); //position value exceeds 
        }
    }
}
```

Make new list, `insertAt("hello", 1)`, `insertAt("world", 2)`. The application shuts down.

Please test your code before putting it up for review. You'll get higher grades too, especially if you show your tests to your professor or whoever is teaching you.

Comment: Why not close the question if there's bugs instead of answering?

Comment: @TopinFrassi As per the [help/on-topic], "To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?" is the criteria we use. From the question, I determine the asker is not a very experienced programmer. He's still learning. I don't think the question was that bad, it just shows a lack of testing, which he might not have learned yet.

Also, correctness in corner-cases is on-topic. To slam the door in the face of one that actively seeks help in a good way whilst showing at least some effort from himself... that's something I wouldn't do.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask it in a way that the question **had** to be closed, I was just wondering what was the best to do. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Made changes and tested, which should have been done before asking such queries. Main intention of this query is to confirm the compliance of six points that is mentioned in the query. Emphasis is on designing Abstraction and providing Encapsulation as mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 8):

Review:

```
public void insertAt(Object item, int position){
    if (position == 1){
        insertFront(item);
        size++;
    }else if(position < 1){
        System.exit(1);
    }else{
        SListNode currentNode = this.head.nth(position);
        if(currentNode != null){
            currentNode.insertAfter(item);
            size++;
        }else{
            System.exit(1); //position value exceeds 
        }
    }
}
```

Don't use `System.exit(1)`. It forcibly shuts down the application. Nobody likes that, because there's nothing they can do at that point. Plus, from the user perspective, they hit "new item" and POOF the whole application is gone. No error message, no possibility for display of instructions (program contains bug! Please look on your desktop and email this file to us!)...

---

A good list (for shopping list) allows me to check if something is already on there (`contains`) and allows me to cross items off my list when I have them (`removeAt`, `remove(object)`).

---

Your comments need to be a bit better.

```
System.exit(1); //position value exceeds
```

Exceeds what? Comments should be clear and precise. Comments should detail the why as well. Any interesting differences in the working of your code compared to similar code (how does your SList differ from `java.util.List`?) could also be valid comments. I'd add a comment to your class stating that it's 1-indexed; that is, you start counting at 1.

Comment: I made this a separate answer because the bugs should stand out more on their own, rather than being part of some larger review.

Comment: Good point for `System.exit()`. It should almost never be use in a normal class. It's such a drastic way of closing the application, no time to close connections or resources. It's rarely a good decision.

Comment: Am a new learner at [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/) online.

Answer (score 2):

The code is slightly convoluted, and there is some fat to be trimmed.

For example, you have list-traversing code in `SListNode.nth()` (working recursively) and `SList.insertEnd()` (using an iterative loop).  You also have node-insertion logic in both `SListNode.insertAfter()`, `SList.insertFront()`, and `SList.insertEnd()`.  Splitting up your code like that makes it harder to follow.  I recommend making your `SListNode` just a "dumb" structure:

```
class SListNode {
    Object item;
    SListNode next;

    SListNode(Object item, SListNode next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

… so that you can centralize all of the intelligence in the `SList` class.  You only need one `SListNode` constructor.

`SList.insertEnd(Object item)` can just call `insertAt(item, size + 1);`

`SList.insertAt()` and `SList.nth()` should perform the bounds checking up front.  Here's how I would write `.insertAt()`:

```
/**
 * Inserts item in the list.  Position 1 puts the new item at the head.
 * Inserting an item at position (size + 1) appends it to the end.
 */
public void insertAt(Object item, int position) {
    if (position < 1 || position > size + 1) {
        // TODO: Error handling
        return;
    } else if (position == 1) {
        insertFront(item);
    } else {
        SListNode prev = this.head;
        for (int i = 2; i < position; i++) {
            prev = prev.next;
        }
        prev.next = new SListNode(item, prev.next);
        size++;
    }   
}
```

The `SList` constructor is actually the same as what Java provides by default, so you could omit it.

Comment: you are right, i can consolidate all intelligence in SList, but i think methods added up in SListNode() because i thought of writing in recursive logic(for practice). Am i correct? If i would write iteratively, I would only need a constructor from SListNode. Modified insertEnd() of SList logic into recursive which required adding insertEnd() in SListNode as well. So, that means taking recusive approach actually complicating the code flow, right?

Comment: i did not get this point: `I'm not sure what you mean by "Abstract Data Type". All I see is a linked list.`

Comment: i will take back this statement: " i think methods added up in SListNode() because i thought of writing in recursive logic(for practice). Am i correct? "

Comment: Recursion is usually avoided in Java due to concerns about performance and stack size limits. However, in programming exercises (which this clearly is — you would never write your own linked list in production code), it's perfectly fine. It would still be better to keep the `SListNode` class dumb, though. You could reformulate `SList.insertAt()` using recursion instead.

Comment: You failed to meet criteria 2 and 3, as Pimgd noted, due to careless bugs. Otherwise, you're on the right track.