# Implementing sequence abstraction

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, inheritance

Below is the code that implements `sequence` abstraction using type abstraction  `Sequence` (in Java):

```
/**
 * 
 * @author mohet01
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class Sequence<T>{

    /**
     * Abstract data type constitutes constructor and selector functions
     * written below under representation that hold below invariant:
     * If a recursive list s is constructed from a first element f and a recursive list r, then
     *    • first(s) returns f, and
     *    • rest(s) returns r, which is a recursive list.
     */



     /* Representation - start */


    //private static Sequence<?> emptyList = null;
    private T item;
    private Sequence<T> restOfTheList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param first
     * @param rest
     */
    public Sequence(T first, Sequence<T> rest){
            this.item = first;
            this.restOfTheList = rest;
    }

    /**
     * Selector function
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private T first(){
        return this.item;
    }

    /**
     * Selector function
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private Sequence<T> rest(){
        return this.restOfTheList;
    }


     /* Representation - end */




     /* User interface - starts */
     /* These methods MUST take help of constructor or selector.*/

    /**
     * length of the list
     * @return
     */

    public final int length(){
        return this.lengthOfTheList(0); 
    }

    private final int lengthOfTheList(int length){
        if(this.rest() == null){
            return length + 1;
        }else{
            return this.rest().lengthOfTheList(length + 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get an item from the given position.
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public final T getItem(int position){
        if(position == 1){
            return this.first();
        }else{
            return this.rest().getItem(position - 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new sequence after deletion of an item at given position
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public final Sequence<T> deleteItem(int position){
        if(position <= this.length() && (position > 0)){
            return this.delete(position);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private final Sequence<T> delete(int position){
        if (position == 1){
            if(this.rest() != null){
                return this.rest().deleteItem(position - 1);
            }else{//last element case
                return null;    
            }
        }   
        else if(this.rest() == null){
            return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), null);
        }
        else{
            return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), this.rest().deleteItem(position - 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create new sequence after inserting a new element at given position
     * @param item
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public final Sequence<T> insertItem(T item, int position){
        if((position <= this.length() + 1) && (position > 0)){
            return this.insert(item, position);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private final Sequence<T> insert(T item, int position){
        if(position == 1){
            return new Sequence<T>(item, this);
        }
        else{
            if(this.rest() == null){
                return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), new Sequence<T>(item, null));
            }
            else{
                return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), this.rest().insert(item, position - 1));
            }

        }
    }

    /* User interface ends */

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sequence<Integer> list = new Sequence<Integer>(4, null);
        //Sequence<Integer> list = new Sequence<Integer>(1, new Sequence<Integer>(2, null));
        //Sequence<Integer> list = new Sequence<Integer>(3, new Sequence<Integer>(2, new Sequence<Integer>(1, null)));
        //list = new Sequence<Integer>(4, list);
        //System.out.println(list.length());
        //list = list.deleteItem(1);
        list = list.insertItem(5, 2);

    }

}
```

---

The above code is tested on [python-tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).

It follows the idea of recursive approach because of this recursive property i.e., item and rest of the sequence unlike [node-based](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63008/37254) sequence.

`public` level access user API's are `final` for these [reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/266334/131582).

It is multi-user/multi-thread safe.

Above code is not measured/intend to write space/time efficient code.

My questions:

1. There are nested `if`..`else` conditions in `deleteItem()` and `insertItem()`. Can this code be more elegant?
2. Does `Sequence` look good to further maintain relations like inheritance with sub-class and composition within other class in/out of package? Assuming this code is written in a package.

Comment: This is really not a generative sequence; it's just a very inefficient linked list. A sequence wouldn't have insert/delete/length. On the other hand, an efficient linked list would maintain a length member so you didn't have to count.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill This sounds like the beginnings of a decent answer--perhaps you could elaborate it into one?

Comment: @200_success For you point: "Your `Sequence<T>`is basically a `LinkedListNode<T>` by another name" How above code is different from `public class SList { private SListNode head; private int size;..}`?

Answer (score 5):

## Minor bug

```
/**
 * Get an item from the given position.
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public final T getItem(int position){
    if(position == 1){
        return this.first();
    }else{
        return this.rest().getItem(position - 1);
    }
}
```

You need to do a lower-bound check here, namely since your `Sequence` is a **`1-index`** based implementation, you need to make sure `position >= 1`. Passing `0` here will result in `NullPointerException` eventually.

## Length checks

Deriving the `Sequence` length can probably be better expressed as:

```
return 1 + (rest() == null ? 0 : rest().length());
```

It's easier to literally express this as "length of sequence is myself and what follows behind", instead of relying on a helper method...

## Unit tests

Please create more unit tests to test the expected behavior for unexpected `position`s, e.g. `0`, negative values, far greater than `length()`, etc.

## Performance

> Above code is not measured/intend to write space/time efficient code.

Ok... but still, the performance is *really bad*... inserting and calculating the length of a `Sequence` is nowhere near instantaneous.

## Other comments

IMO, your implementation depends heavily on knowing the exact positions or length of a `Sequence` at any time, it will facilitate the usage if you have wrapper methods to add to the front, the back, or even just a constructor that accepts only a seed value. Also, do consider implementing the [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, so that users of `Sequence` can iterate through them.

Answer (score 2):

Re 1.: If you `return` in an `if` block an `else` is pointless since it will be never reached anyway. Thus `insert()` can be reduced to:

```
if (position == 1) {
    return new Sequence<T>(item, this);
}
if (this.rest() == null) {
    return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), new Sequence<T>(item, null));
}
return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), this.rest().insert(item, position - 1));
```

And `delete()`, `lengthOfTheList()`, `getItem()` likewise.

Answer (score 2):

Each `Sequence<T>` is immutable.  You should make that obvious by marking `item` and `restOfTheList` as `final` members.

---

Are you a fan of [public-private partnerships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public%e2%80%93private_partnership)?  I think that you can get the job done just as effectively if you cut out the private sector.  For example, @h.j.k has noted that `length()` can just be:

```
public int length() {
    return this.rest() == null ? 1 : 1 + this.rest().length();
}
```

The `delete(int position)` method is more troubling.  If the `position == 1` condition is met, then you call `this.rest().deleteItem(0)`, which recurses to `this.rest().rest().deleteItem(-1)`, `this.rest().rest().rest().deleteItem(-2)`, and so on.  That works, but you end up copying all of the subsequent nodes for no good reason.

I recommend that you avoid calling `.length()` at all, since that is an O(*n*) operation.  (You would end up unnecessarily copying the list, though, in the case where the position to be deleted is past the end of the list.)

```
public Sequence<T> deleteItem(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        return this.rest();
    } else if (position < 1 || this.rest() == null) {
        return this;  // Nothing to delete
    } else {
        return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), this.rest().delete(position - 1));
    }
}
```

The same goes for `insertItem()`.

I'm concerned about the error handling for `insertItem()` (and, to a lesser extent, `deleteItem()`).  If you try to insert something beyond one position past the end, then the data is silently discarded — with no indication in the return value, and no exception thrown.

Comment: why do we learn node based list in classroom? when the above  representation is more-intuitive? Intuitive with an idea: `item and rest of the list`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your `Sequence<T>` is basically a `LinkedListNode<T>` by another name.

Comment: @overexchange because [to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/implementing-sequence-abstraction#comment152583_84783).

Comment: I think this condition `this.rest() == null`does not look necessary in "elseif" of your above answer, and the code looks very elegant!!!

Comment: When you say, "Each Sequence<T> is immutable" that mean, the above sequence will be destroyed(after creation) only when jvm goes down, correct?

Comment: For your point: "you avoid calling .length() at all" But what if user says position `5`(say) when sequence only has 2 elements(for example)?

Comment: For your point: "The same goes for insertItem()", Yes I followed the same logic in `insertItem()` But can I avoid this code? `if(this.rest() == null){return new Sequence<T>(this.first(), new Sequence<T>(item, null));
   }`